# Telerik RadEditor controls are disabled in inline editing mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, radeditor

I have some custom drop downs under EditorToolGroup in RadEditor. I wanted to enable a drop down when I am in inline html editing mode. How to do it?

```
<telerik:RadEditor Skin="Metro" ID="HTMLEditor"
                        OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad"
                        OnClientSelectionChange="OnClientSelectionChange"
                        OnClientCommandExecuting="OnClientCommandExecutingHTML"
                        NewLineMode="Br"
                        EditModes="Design,Html"
                        ContentAreaMode="Iframe"
                        OnClientModeChange="OnClientModeChange"
                        Height="680px" Width="100%"
                        runat="server" EnableResize="false" ExternalDialogsPath="~/EditorDialogs"
                        ContentFilters="IECleanAnchors,FixEnclosingP,FixUlBoldItalic,MottEmStrong,RemoveScripts,ConvertToXhtml,ConvertInlineStylesToAttributes"
                        DialogsCssFile="~/styles/Editor_LinkManagerMetro.css">
<Tools>
                            <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                               <telerik:EditorTool Name="SaveDesign" Text="Save" />
                                <telerik:EditorTool Name="SaveAs" Text="Save As My Template" ShowText="false" ShowIcon="true" />
                                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Undo" ShowIcon="true" />
                                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Redo" ShowIcon="true" />
                                <telerik:EditorSeparator Visible="true" />
<telerik:EditorDropDown Name="EnableThisDropdown" Width="125px" Text="Select" RenderMode="Lightweight" />
```